# Difference in scope of argument and return value

Tags: python, function, design-patterns

The example below is a no frills version of something I saw out in the wild.

```
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def _get(self, path, **kwargs):
         self.session.get("etc")

def ScopedObject(cls):
    return cls

ScopedClient = ScopedObject(Client) # Why??
```

What is the use of the last line?

Here is an example I tried out to make sense of what happening. (Code above is simply for context).

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, v):
...             self.x = v
...
>>> def scope(cls): return cls
...
>>> a = A
>>> b = scope(a)
>>> a
<class __main__.A at 0x10989c2f0>
>>> b
<class __main__.A at 0x10989c2f0>
>>> a(1)
<__main__.A instance at 0x1098df910>
>>> b(1)
<__main__.A instance at 0x1098df870>
>>> a(1)
<__main__.A instance at 0x1098df910>
```

So, okay it causes their instances to be different.
But I could have accomplished the same thing by doing:

```
>>> c = a
>>> c(1)
<__main__.A instance at 0x1098df870>
```

Which returns the exact same instance as `b`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The code you've posted is pointless. Perhaps the original code was also pointless, or perhaps you accidentally removed the point.

Comment: I wouldn't have closed the question because the answer is clear: As you correctly deduced, `a` and `b` point to the same thing -- so the `ScopedObject` function does nothing useful.

Comment: Yes, I agree the code I found appears to be pointless. However, I saw this "design choice" repeated several times in production code, which makes me doubt that it is in fact pointless. Hence, why I asked the question: What am I missing?

Comment: As far as we can tell from your example, you are missing nothing.